# How to get SSIS environment variables using Python?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, pyodbc

I am converting a SSIS project into Python. Here is a problem that I encountered recently, that I have no idea how to get environment variables of SSIS.

For example the following SQL code for SSIS:

```
EXEC SSIS.proc_PackageInitalisation
 @packageExecutionInstanceGuid = ?
,@packageGuid = ?
,@packageName = ?
,@packageVersionGuid = ?
,@packageVersionMajor = ?
,@packageVersionMinor = ?
,@packageVersionBuild = ?
,@packageMachineName = ?
,@packageUserName = ?
,@packageProductVersion = ?
,@packageStartTime = ?
,@packageParentExecutionId = ?
,@executionId = ? OUTPUT
```

Only `@packageParentExecutionId` and `@executionId` are user defined variables, while the rest variables are in `System` namespace.

So when I use `pyodbc.cursor.execute()`, there is no way I can initialize these variables.

Please help me to work around this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I dont know python. But as for SSIS, I believe that these variables are not dynamic (i.e. stored in the xml). So, if you can parse the XML files, you maybe able to get these values. On the other hand, if the values are dynamic and derived only at runtime, then you would actually have to run the package and save them temporarily in OS Environment variables.

Comment: I'm assuming the package is stored in stored in SQL Server, and not on a filesystem. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're constrained by the 2008 version of SQL Server, you're better off using the Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html) module to call [dtexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) directly. If the package is stored in SQL Server, the syntax would look something like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['dtexec', '/sql <package_path>'])
```

The alternative is to use xp_cmdshell to call `dtexec` from T-SQL, but that comes with the usual security caveats mentioned in  the *Remarks* and *Permissions* sections [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). **I don't see any need for this method since you're already planning to use Python to run the package.**

If/when you upgrade to SQL Server 2012 and use the [project deployment model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213290.aspx), you can call the [catalog.create_execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878034.aspx) stored procedure from T-SQL.